I have 5 virtual sites running on one apache2 / ubuntu 20.04 aws instance, editing the virtual (sites-available/*.conf) doesn't change anything
I've not been long into Apache 2, but have not come across this before. It is completely out foxing me.
I'm editing using nano on ssh on a lightsail instance
I have a seperate .conf file for each v-server.

site_one.conf - contains 2 V-Hosts, 1 on port 80 - directs to site on
443 - running .net
site_two.conf - contains 2 vvosts, both on port 80 (brochure sites)- both direct to a .net server (basic)
site_three.conf - much the same, except to 443 - running on .net server
site_four.conf - again much the same (but inclides a non directed v-host for an api.)

I don't have 000-default enabled (it does not appear in the sites-enabled file list)
I have:

a2dissite / a2ensite each config file, reload and restart (I now have an sh that does it for me)
rebooted server (quite a few times)
Just changed on v-server to point to a different website, then went through every process imaginable (as above), but http://site_one.com doen not go to new redirect.

Can any one help.
I'm guessing that apache2 is caching the config somewhere. I'd love to know where this is and delete it.
My next option is to backup all, and reinstall apache... but I have ssl on all the servers.
All but one of the servers are working and on line, I need to get the one that isn't working.

apache does not cache the config in another file.  it literally uses the config file it reads.  maybe if you show us the config file(s) you have, we may be able to help you quicker.

Do not forget to confirm the DNS record for your domain points to the correct IP. I have seen many people spend hours on Apache when the problem was an incomplete copy/paste in the domain registrar
